# регулярное выражение для пагинации в .htaccess

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Добрый день! Нужно, чтобы ссылка в пагинации убирались точки, прошу помочь создать регулярное выражение для .htaccess

Например:

```
http://homeopatia63.ru/catalog/knigi/...?PAGEN_1=3
```

должна переходить на

```
http://homeopatia63.ru/catalog/knigi/?PAGEN_1=3
```

и

```
http://homeopatia63.ru/catalog/knigi/...?PAGEN_1=2
```

должна переходить на

```
http://homeopatia63.ru/catalog/knigi/?PAGEN_1=2
```

Пробовал прописать

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)..(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Ломается сайт

Comment: откуда у вас вообще такая шляпа с точками берется?

Comment: teran. Без понятия, просто прихоть заказчика

Comment: `catalog/knigi` это изменяемая часть или постоянная?

Comment: teran, catalog/knigi постоянная

Comment: вам нужно чтобы по ссылке с точками просто открывался контент без точек, или чтобы происходил редирект на новую ссылку? ибо в вашем примере указан 301й редирект

Comment: teran, чтобы происходил редирект на ссылку без точек